# Is there any way to test iOS apps on React Native without a MacBook?

Tags: ios, emulation

I was running my app on MacBook iOS Emulator but it's an old one and it doesn't work well, so I was curious is there any way to test it on cloud like test 30 devices same time, I know you can run MacOS on VMWare or VirtualBox but it performs worse lol.

Comment: You don't have to use a Macbook. You could use an iMac or a Mac mini . There are cloud Mac providers. Perhaps you could use one of those to build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good solution, all workaround are just not worth, compromises performance, makes development impossible,

get an old mac mini

Comment: Thanks for your comment, my old 2012 MacBook pro actually works well with emulator, but when it comes using chrome and bunch of vs code extensions it goes bad. These devices are really powerful, I should get a new one.